# undefined reference to cv::inpaint - Error 1

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, image-processing, opencv

I need a help. 
Few months ago I make this c++ code in Visual studio on Windows. I make .exe file from that code and everything work fine just like this. That is simple code for image-processing. Now I trying to do same thing in Eclipse on Linux so that I can put executable file on Linux web server. But I have this error:

```
In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x317): undefined reference to `cv::inpaint(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, double, int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [inpaint] Error 1
```

I use OpencCV 2.4.1 library. This is source code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/photo/photo.hpp"
#include <iostream>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
Mat img, img0, maska;
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

...
   }
Mat inpainted;
inpaint(img0, img, inpainted, 2, CV_INPAINT_NS);
char imeobr[256] = "images/img-uploads/finish";
strcat( imeobr, argv[1] );
strcat( imeobr, ".jpg" );
imwrite(imeobr, inpainted);
return 0;
}
```

I think that is a problem in input source, because is not a fixed name of input images. But, I need dynamically change input source for every user of application. 
Please help people. What I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Undefined reference error happens when you omit to link a library:

in the preferences of your project:

```
C/C++ Build -> GCC C++ Linker -> Libraries
```

have you entered libopencv_imgproc library in Libraries(-l)?

## update

Just for testing, I've created my  program:

```
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  Mat img, img0;
  Mat inpainted;
  inpaint(img0, img, inpainted, 2, CV_INPAINT_NS);
}
```

in libraries I've linked:

```
opencv_imgproc 
opencv_highgui
opencv_core
```

Everything works fine.. Try it and tell me!

Comment: Yes, I entered libraries. All libraries like opencv_imgproc, opencv_highgui... But not libopencv_imgproc. If I do that console have new error: cannot find -llibopencv_imgproc

Comment: And I include paths in my project also

Comment: I test OpenCv and libs using openCv example and all work fine

Answer (score 3):

you need to include:

-lopencv_photo

Comment: This is the answer